# Tiny box js error: [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I add tinybox to my website, when run any tinybox show, e.g:

`TINY.box.show({html:'This is a warning!',animate:false,close:false,boxid:'error',top:5})`

I get this error: http://screencast.com/t/TKzIrXbgBU

No error on console.

Anyone help me in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not an error. `[object Object]` means you are attempting to output an object.

Answer (score 0):

you probably using old version of tinybox. install tinybox2

http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/